# c# / ASP.net / PostBack /Open port

Tags: c#, asp.net, arduino

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace Smart_House
{
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SerialPort serijska_vrata;



    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        /*Inicializacija dropdownList*/

        DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM3");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM2");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM1");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM4");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM5");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM6");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM7");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM8");
        DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM9");

        /*Inicializacija Serialport*/

        serijska_vrata = new SerialPort();
        serijska_vrata.PortName = "COM3";
        serijska_vrata.BaudRate = 9600;

       if(!IsPostBack)
        {

            serijska_vrata.Open();
            Button3.Text = "\uf011";
        }

    }

    protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


    }



    static bool on_off_namizna = false;


    protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        if (on_off_namizna == false)
        {

                serijska_vrata.Write("1");
                button_style.Href = "Buttonon.css";
                label_style.Href = "labelon.css";
                on_off_namizna = true;

          }
        else if (on_off_namizna == true)
        {


                serijska_vrata.Write("0");
                button_style.Href = "Buttonoff.css";
                label_style.Href = "labeloff.css";
                on_off_namizna = false;
          }

    }


}
```

}

I want to write code to control arduino, and open port the first time that page loads, and then close themn manual, i tried the above code but the port doesnt open, if i do it without if(!IsPostback) then it works, but i would like to open port just the first time, please help.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM3");
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM2");
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM1");
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM4");
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM5");
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM6");
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM7");
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM8");
    DropDownList1.Items.Add("COM9");

    /*Inicializacija Serialport*/

    serijska_vrata = new SerialPort();
    serijska_vrata.PortName = "COM3";
    serijska_vrata.BaudRate = 9600;



        serijska_vrata.Open();
        Button3.Text = "\uf011";
    }
```

Because if you keep the DropDownList ADD method outside the (!IsPostPack) it will keep pushing items inside the List.

Comment: Doesnt work i get error System.NullReferenceException {"object reference not set to an instance of an object"} at "serijska_vrata.Write("1");